# why am receiving a mapping exception with the root cause as SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 45

Tags: hibernate, exception, hibernate-mapping, saxparseexception, mappingexception

**Buyer.hbm.xml**
is the buyer mapping file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="entity.Buyer" table="buyer">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="string">
            <column name="username" length="25" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="fname" type="string">
            <column name="fname" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lname" type="string">
            <column name="lname" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="phoneno" type="int">
            <column name="phoneno" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="location" type="string">
            <column name="location" length="16" not-null="true" />
        </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Buyer.java**
is a POJO class that is created to be an entity from an sql database

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Tariana
 */
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByUsername", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.username = :username")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByFname", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.fname = :fname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByLname", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.lname = :lname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByEmail", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.email = :email")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByPhoneno", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.phoneno = :phoneno")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByPassword", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.password = :password")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByLocation", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.location = :location")})
public class Buyer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String fname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String lname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int phoneno;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String password;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String location;

    public Buyer() {
    }

    public Buyer(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Buyer(Integer id, String username, String fname, String lname, String email, int phoneno, String password, String location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
        this.password = password;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(int phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Buyer)) {
            return false;
        }
        Buyer other = (Buyer) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Buyer[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
    
}
```

**Registration.java**
is supposed to provide persistence for data from a jsp file into an sql database

```html
import entity.Buyer;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.hibernate.*; 
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.metamodel.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {   
        
        Buyer buyerreg = new Buyer();
        
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phoneno");
        int phoneno = Integer.parseInt(phone);
        String location = request.getParameter("location");
        
        buyerreg.setEmail(email);
        buyerreg.setPassword(password);
        buyerreg.setFname(fname);
        buyerreg.setLname(lname);
        buyerreg.setUsername(username);
        buyerreg.setPhoneno(phoneno);
        buyerreg.setLocation(location);
        
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Buyer.class)
            .configure();
            
        
        StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .build();
        Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();

        SessionFactory factory;  
        factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        Session session=factory.openSession();  

        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        session.persist(buyerreg);           
        t.commit();    
        session.close();    
        System.out.println("success"); 
        response.sendRedirect("shop.jsp");
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**
is my hibernate configuration file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
            "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkulimaonline</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="entity.Buyer" package="entity" resource="entity/Buyer.hbm.xml"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses"><list><value>entity.Buyer</value></list>
    </property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Error**
that is being displayed on the browser

```html
message invalid configuration

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2158)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
 Register.doGet(Register.java:38)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)


root cause
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 45; Element type "list" must be declared.
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1906)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
 org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2155)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
 Register.doGet(Register.java:38)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your exception says, there is a problem with XML parser (SAXParseException). If you look, at the defined [DTD](http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd) you can check that under  element there is no  element allowed. I think you copied some content from spring configuration.

SAXParseException won't be showing if you delete those lines from your hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<property name="annotatedClasses"><list><value>entity.Buyer</value></list>
</property>
```

Comment: Grzegorz Sancewicz do you have any insight on the issue below?? about the standardserviceregistry not working and the session.commit() only accepting an 
entity class generated by netbeans from the database but when I used my own entity class with @Entity annotation it did not work... both issues provided this error "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: entity.Buyer"

Answer (score 0):

I removed the annotated class from the hibernate.cfg.xml file. I was not using Spring. But somehow this worked
**I do not know why this piece of code does not work** org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: entity.Buyer this error persists so I commented the code

```html
SessionFactory factory; 
        StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .build();
        Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        Session session=factory.openSession(); 
        
        
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        session.persist(buyerreg);           
        t.commit();    
        session.close();
```

This is what I used instead

**hibernate.cfg.config**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkulimaonline</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Registration.java** I commented the code that was not working and this alternative somehow worked

```html
import entity.Buyer;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {   
        
        Buyer buyerreg = new Buyer();
        
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phoneno");
        int phoneno = Integer.parseInt(phone);
        String location = request.getParameter("location");
        
        buyerreg.setEmail(email);
        buyerreg.setPassword(password);
        buyerreg.setFname(fname);
        buyerreg.setLname(lname);
        buyerreg.setUsername(username);
        buyerreg.setPhoneno(phoneno);
        buyerreg.setLocation(location);
        
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Buyer.class)
            .addResource("entity/Buyer.hbm.xml")
            .configure();
        
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .build();        
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(buyerreg);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        
        System.out.println("success"); 
        response.sendRedirect("shop.jsp");
        
        /*SessionFactory factory; 
        StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .build();
        Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        Session session=factory.openSession(); 
        
        
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        session.persist(buyerreg);           
        t.commit();    
        session.close();
        */
    }
}
```

**Buyer.java** I had to use the auto-generated java class from the database... My own creation had this error even after using the @Entity annotation **"org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: entity.Buyer"**

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Tariana
 */
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByUsername", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.username = :username")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByFname", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.fname = :fname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByLname", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.lname = :lname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByEmail", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.email = :email")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByPhoneno", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.phoneno = :phoneno")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByPassword", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.password = :password")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Buyer.findByLocation", query = "SELECT b FROM Buyer b WHERE b.location = :location")})
public class Buyer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String fname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String lname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int phoneno;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String password;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String location;

    public Buyer() {
    }

    public Buyer(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Buyer(Integer id, String username, String fname, String lname, String email, int phoneno, String password, String location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
        this.password = password;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(int phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Buyer)) {
            return false;
        }
        Buyer other = (Buyer) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Buyer[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
    
}
```

and the **Buyer.hbm.xml** remained the same

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="entity.Buyer" table="buyer">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="string">
            <column name="username" length="25" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="fname" type="string">
            <column name="fname" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lname" type="string">
            <column name="lname" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="phoneno" type="int">
            <column name="phoneno" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="location" type="string">
            <column name="location" length="16" not-null="true" />
        </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```